# Need a little clarification on $\left \| v \right \|= \sqrt{\langle v,v \rangle}$ and $\langle v,v\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I'm very confused of $\left \| v \right \|= \sqrt{\left \langle v,v \right \rangle}$

Let's say $v=\begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
3\\ 
5
\end{pmatrix}$

**What would be $\left \| v \right \|$? Is it the same as $\left | v \right |$. so the length of the vector v?**

$\left \| v \right \|= \sqrt{2^2+3^2+5^2}$ is correct for this example?

What is $\sqrt{\left \langle v,v \right \rangle}$?

Is it $\sqrt{\left \langle v,v \right \rangle}= \sqrt{2\cdot 2+3 \cdot 3 + 5 \cdot 5}$?

Should be correct because we get that $\left \| v \right \|= \sqrt{\left \langle v,v \right \rangle}$.

And what is the mathematical term/name of $\left \| v \right \|$? What's the name of $\left \langle v,v \right \rangle$? I found a lot confusing stuff on the internet, calling it scalar product, euclidean norm or just length of vector. What is it? I really hope you can help me I'm going crazy about it.

Comment: $\|v\|$ is called the **norm** of $v$.  Some writers may use $|v|$ for the norm of a vector instead.  They believe you will not be confused if it is the same notation as the absolute value of a scalar.

Comment: @gedgar Thank you for first clarification. Then $\sqrt{\left \langle v,v \right \rangle}$ should be the norm of $v$ too. But what is name of $\left \langle v,v \right \rangle$?

Comment: Inner product or dot product.

Comment: @tenepolis All of these descriptions you found "on the internet" are the same.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern Inner product = skalar product?

Comment: Yes, although _inner product_ is used in a more general context (see e.g. my answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $\left \langle \vec v,\vec w \right \rangle$ is used to denote an **inner product** of vectors $\vec v$ and $\vec w$. If you are working in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (or more generally in $\mathbb{R}^n$), a well-known example is the standard **dot product** (or *scalar product*) which is also written as $\vec v \cdot \vec w$ and given by $\vec v \cdot \vec w = v_1w_1 + v_2w_2 + v_3w_3$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

You can always construct/associate a **norm** $\left\| \vec v \right\|$ with an inner product via $\left\| \vec v \right\|=\sqrt{\left \langle \vec v,\vec v \right \rangle}$. If you do so with the standard dot product, the formula for the norm in $\mathbb{R}^3$ reduces to the well-known:
$$\left\| \vec v \right\| = \sqrt{\left \langle \vec v,\vec v \right \rangle} = \sqrt{ \vec v \cdot \vec v} = \sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2+v_3^2}$$
But you could work with another inner product, resulting in a different norm. So you could see an inner product $\left \langle \vec v,\vec w \right \rangle$ as a generalization of the dot product $\vec v \cdot \vec w$ and via that inner product, arrive at a more general concept of *norm*, besides the standard Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 1):

$\langle x,y\rangle$ is called the [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) (it is also called the scalar product in the Euclidean spaces). If we have a vector space with the inner product, then we can also define the norm corresponding to the inner prodcut on that vector space by setting $\|x\|=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$. In the $d$-dimensional Euclidean spaces, the scalar product is defined as
$$
\langle x,y\rangle=x^Ty=x_1y_1+\ldots+x_dy_d.
$$
Hence, the norm of the vector (or the length of the vector) is given by
$$
\|x\|=|x|=\sqrt{x_1^2+\ldots+x_d^2}.
$$